# Need gradient color in Highstock Line chart + Angular 5.0

Tags: angular, angular5, highcharts, linechart

I have used Highstock line chart in my one of Angular 5.0 project. It looks like below screenshot.
[image]

But I need gradient color in this chart like below screenshot.
[image]

Can you please help me with this concern.
Thanks in advance.

**Edited**

I am adding

```
var Highcharts = require('highcharts/highstock'); 
require('indicators')(Highcharts); 
require('sma')(Highcharts); 
var Highcharts = require('highcharts/highstock'); 
require('indicators')(Highcharts);
```

But its show me error like:

**Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'highcharts/indicators' in filepath**

Comment: Change the type of your series to **area** and use gradient options from the following demo: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-time-series/

Comment: Yuppp. It's working. Thanks for the help

Comment: @KamilKulig Also, I need indicates for highchart or highstocj in angular 5. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: Sure, check out **the official Highcharts wrapper for angular**: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular

Comment: Thanks for your response, but we have already used this wrapper but there are no any indicators in this wrapper.

Comment: Have you attached indicators as a module(s)?: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/technical-indicator-series Target of the link from my previous comment (*To load a module* section) explains how to do it in angular.

Comment: @KamilKulig I have updated question for it. Please check it and help me on this concern. Please check Edited part.

Comment: Firstly: the last two lines of the code that you attached are a duplice of first two ones. Remove last two lines.Secondly: are you sure that you've  provided the correct path to the indicators file?

Comment: Yes, I had removed duplicates. But where I should give the path for Indicators and what is that path? I had only import import { ChartModule } from 'angular-highcharts'; and import charts using import { Chart,StockChart } from 'angular-highcharts';

Comment: `angular-highcharts` is not the official Highcharts wrapper for Angular 2+, see `angular-highcharts` GitHub repo for info about that wrapper. Your questions are not precise enough to provide an answer - please add live demo, error messages, detailed info. `'highcharts/indicators'` is path to folder - use `'highcharts/indicators/indicators'` for core of the indicators module and `highcharts/indicators/xxx`for xxx indicator - e.g. sma, rsi, etc.